# Is there a word for when an action has an effect opposite to the one intended?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase to express the concept of an action having the opposite effect of the expected outcome?

For example, a drug taken to cure headaches that actually causes headaches, or an advertising campaign designed to deter smoking that leads to an increase in smoking.

Comment: The Dutch languagehas a word for this, 'averechts', but it seems [awkward/context dependant to translate](http://www.majstro.com/dictionaries/Dutch-English/averechts).

Comment: A single word meaning "producing or capable of producing a desired effect" is **efficacious**.

**Inefficacious** means _not_ having the desired effect. That might be useful to you, even if not having the desired effect is not necessarily the same as having the _opposite_ effect.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A common idiom expressing this concept is "to backfire". For example:

- The campaign to reduce smoking backfired.

Comment: Does that mean the campaign increased smoking or does it mean the campaign was criticized?

Comment: It increased smoking - **backfired**  past participle, past tense of **back·fire** (Verb) 
(of a plan or action) _Rebound adversely on the originator; have the opposite effect to what was intended._

Comment: That pun is terrible. Worst one of the day. +1

Comment: No, no, @cwallenpoole. Sausage puns are the wurst.

Answer (score 9):

**Counter-productive** seems to fit your request pretty closely.  The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/42944?redirectedFrom=counterproductive#eid) defines it as:

> Having the opposite of the desired effect, tending to act against the attainment of an objective.

It’s a comparative neologism (apparently originally from US bureaucrat-speak in the 60’s), but is now well-established on both sides of the Atlantic in both formal and informal use:

> *The drug laws are counter-productive, and David Cameron knows it.*
>                   — [Tom Chivers, in the Daily Telegraph](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/tomchiversscience/100137480/david-cameron-knows-the-drug-laws-arent-working-his-failure-to-change-them-is-simple-cowardice/)

> *But you’re right, they wouldn’t sue him (even if they had a case) because it’d just be counter-productive.*
>                   — [lightlee.tumblr.com](http://lightlee.tumblr.com/post/17250638269) [random Google result looking for casual use]

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [Paradoxical Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxical_reaction). In general terms, I think you call something like that a *paradox.*

Comment: '*Paradoxical Reaction*' applies only in pharmacology. And  *paradox* does not fit the description of 'an action that has the opposite effect to that intended.'

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may also be considered irony; specifically [situational irony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Situational_irony).

Such situations could therefore be described as ironic, but probably only upon second reference, when the facts of the matter had already been established.

e.g.:

> First mention: *The headache-treating drug was known to have caused headaches.*
>
> Second mention: *Dr. Stephens reported the drug's ironic effect to the FDA.*

Answer (score 2):

I just found [this term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) recently and thought that it will be useful for somebody:

> The **Streisand effect** is the phenomenon whereby an attempt to hide or remove a piece of information has the unintended consequence of publicizing the information more widely, usually facilitated by the Internet.
>
> [Wikipedia]

This term is now specific to mass media / Internet, but it will be possibly penetrating in the other relevant fields. However, general concept here is a bit more specific here: forbidding something can possibly rise an interest in something and thus cause a more wide spread (i.e. an opposite effect of intended action).

Answer (score 0):

Macmillan Dictionary: do someone​/​something a disservice​/​do a disservice to someone​/​something

to do something that makes people’s opinion of someone or something not as good as it should be
To describe her as just a journalist is to do her a disservice.
He is doing himself a disservice by allowing his songs to be so badly performed.